# Redux store: how to subscribe to actual changes in a component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Several of my components should be rendered only once, since then I just want them to listen to the changes in a global store and act correspondingly. But I can't make it: *store.subscribe*, and *redux-watch* I tried fired only when data has been dispatched but not when the store actually changed what means the corresponding function can't use **this.props.bla** because it's not updated yet. Is there some solution allowing to know when **this.props.bla** actually changed without using **bla** in the render function?

The example of a component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { 
         position: state.position //<== when to know for sure it changed?
    };
};

class MyComp extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);    
        this.state = {
            number: 0
        };
        store.subscribe(() => {
            const currentState = store.getState();
            // even if I have the updated value here in currentState, there are not guarantees this.props.position already changed.
        });
    }
    calculate = ()=>{
       // Do some calculation with this.props.position and change the number.
    }
    render(){
       return <div>{this.state.number}</div>;
   }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComp);
```

Comment: You can subscribe to changes in the redux store by subscribing *to* the store. Don't use `store.subscribe` directly. Use the [connect](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#connect) HOC or the [useSelector](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector) react hook to connect to a listen for specific changes.

Comment: Sorry, but Redux is such a pain in the .... Just changed over to React Query and I'm loving it. I can literally go to a page showing 4 database records, go to my database tool and delete a record, then the moment I click on my browser window again it updates. You can also cancel any existing queries, forcing React Query to refetch the data again.

Comment: @DrewReese I'm already using connect but I don't know how to listen to changes if I don't put props in the render function. Can you give an example of such a component (maybe you'd create an answer?) Thanks!

Comment: @TonyDrummond Thanks for your advice! I will think to use something else too. Does Reac Query allows you to have a central store like redux store. I need multiple components to use some global source.

Comment: @mimic - I just made this video for someone else today that briefly walks through it. I am a newer developer (3 months experience in MERN stack) and was able to convert my whole app over while eliminating 1,500 lines of Redux actions, constants, reducers, and other BS. Here you go: https://youtu.be/rb7ZDj-0NWU

Comment: Perhaps I don't quite understand what you think your issue is. When the redux store updates all subscribed components receive the new store/state object. When the mapped props (or redux context) updates, the component rerenders with the updated redux store/state value. I could try providing an answer, but that could prove difficult if we don't actually know what your issue is and what *your* code is doing. Could you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code?

Comment: @TonyDrummond Redux (and by extension, react-redux) is fine, albeit a little verbose. If the boilerplately-ness of older react-redux is too much for you then I suggest you check out [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) from the same team that brought you react-redux. It's essentially another abstraction level over react-redux that handles the "boilerplate" code for you. On top of that, it encapsulates the reducer logic so you don't have to be as concerned about state mutability.

Comment: @DrewReese The issue is I don't want to use the render function to update values from the store. So I need to figure out a way to know about changes but without rerendering the component.

Comment: I still don't follow, the `render` function is supposed to be a pure function without side-effects, it shouldn't be updating anything. If you are referring to the function body of a functional component, it again, should be a pure function free of side-effects. Perhaps if you show what you are trying to do it will be clearer what you want.

Comment: @DrewReese thank you, but after using React Query I'm never going back to Redux :). React query handles the entire store - I didn't have to set anything up.

Comment: Have you read the redux docs for the [store subscribe](https://redux.js.org/api/store#subscribelistener). "Adds a change listener. It will be called any time an action is dispatched, and some part of the state tree may potentially have changed. You may then call `getState()` to read the current state tree inside the callback." Have you tried getting the current state in the callback?

Comment: @DrewReese I don't ask how to see the value inside the callback. I need a reliable way to read the changes AFTER they are done, and not in the callback. The workflow is: 1) changes in the store made 2) a component knows about it and 3) calls the corresponding function 4) that reads changed data from the store. The render function has a direct effect - it rerenders my component. The component has a render function but it works mostly with other data that are not put in the render function. What I need is a reliable way to know about changes made in the store.

Comment: @DrewReese I added the example of the component.

Comment: So you just want to know when `state.position`/`props.position` value updates? Implement `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method and compare `prevProps.position !== this.props.position` and do what you need to do.

Comment: @DrewReese you are right, I just want to know when this.props.value changed, let me try this solution.

Comment: @DrewReese It worked!! Can you please add your comment as an answer, I will mark it as a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to "respond" to a specific prop value updating then you should implement the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method. In your case if you need to know when the injected `position` prop value has updated, add a condition to compare the previous `position` prop value against the current `position` prop value.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.position !== this.props.position) {
    // position value updated!
  }
}
```

Comment: I have another problem - for some reason, when redux store value is changed, my render() is called but not componentDidUpdate() and I can't figure out why. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @mimic I can't really imagine a scenario where `render` could be called when updating the DOM and somehow `componentDidUpdate` not be called. Feel free to ask a new question on SO and ping me here with a link to it, I can take a look when I've a moment. At a minimum it'll be more visible and you can get more eyes on it more quickly.

Comment: Thanks, Drew! I actually found that I mount the component instead of refreshing it haha - that's why it was not called but componentDidMount() was :)